# Inactive users getting points and badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I think the problem with stackoverflow is that **inactive users** get their experience as well.

E.g. If I ask some good questions or if I provide some good answers, I don't have to do anything next x years and I will get many points and badges despite of the fact, that I am not visiting the website at all.

Comment: Not always..... By the way, what do you want to ask?

Comment: I would think a good question or answer deserves up-votes even if the user is not connected.

Comment: Why do you think this is a **problem** ?

Comment: Is someone trying to mess with my comfortable SO rep pension? That's dangerous, man. I know people.

Comment: Now I understand that you do not want to make users dependent on it. The great value lies in the content only.

Answer (score 20):

The emphasis is on content and not users.

A highly voted post would suggest good content regardless of the OP's visitation frequency...

Even if a user is deleted from the system, his/her contributions will still be available.

Here is an example of this - [Convert a hexadecimal string to an integer efficiently in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-base-10-efficiently-in-c)
<sub>( looking for a better example of a quality post if any one can help out please...)</sub>

I might pop in every other Friday to make a contribution but should my contribution be worth less because I am not a frequent visitor of the site?

> **Disclosure** - I *am* frequently here though...

Comment: If the emphasis is on content, then it is alright. Because if it wasn't the case, users must have been losing their 'experience'

Comment: @mrl - Agreed, luckily [its always Friday in Iceland](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54746/172936)...

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely acceptable. We people see movie producers producing movies out of public demand, or a novelist writing great novels. If they are good, people accept them whole heartedly even decades after their release. That's how it is. If you ask a great question or post a great answer, you'll be praised for ever.

And mind you!!! This is not the case in just Stack Overflow, or other SE sites, This is a global human behaviour.

Comment: I think you are comparing incomparable. A movie / novel is an art. IT is changing. It must be held actual. Questions should be updated and improved.

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me: I really don't think so. Everything in this world is comparable to every other thing in some or the other way.... Here,  I compare  movies/novels and questions/answers because both of them are popular  and liked only if their concept is new and creative, no matter if they are art or technology...